# C pointers : Memory access

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I was practising memory allocation questions in C when I came across this code snippet :

```
int a[3][4] = {{7,3,5,6},{1,10,23,18},{64,45,92,85}};

int(*p)[4] = a;
printf("%d ",(*(*p + (9 - 2 * 3 + 1)) + 2));
```

The answer turns out to be 8 but 8 is not present in the whole array.
Can anyone please explain what is happening here?

Comment: I get 3 from this code. https://godbolt.org/z/x7axWxbav

Answer (score -2):

Yes I got the answer.
Turns out p is getting dereferenced first and then 2 is added to it. So p points to 6 and gets dereferenced and 6+2 = 8.

Comment: The code in the question prints “3”, not “8”, except possibly in an exceptionally pedantic C implementation. `*p` is the `int [4]` that `p` points to, which is the first subarray of `a`, `a[0]`. It is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, `a[0][0]`. Then `9 - 2 * 3 + 1`is 4. Adding 4 to the pointer to `&a[0][0]` produces `&a[0][4]`, which is a valid address (one past the end of an object), but dereferencing it is technically not defined by the C standard. Dereferencing it in most C implementations produces the value `a[1][0]`, which is 1. Adding 2 to that produces 3.